# share "user settings" between Visual Studio Code and SQL Operations Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-data-studio

**How can I share "user settings" between Visual Studio Code and SQL Operations Studio?**  For [a contrived] example, if I set `"editor.detectIndentation": false`, then that should be reflected in both applications.

I'm hoping there's a way to simply have both applications hit the same "settings.json" folder.  (If so, I would imagine that settings that only apply to one application would be ignored by the other, much like unrecognized settings in one application are already.)